# Postfix secondary with OpenDKIM

Tags: postfix-mta, dkim

I can't figure out how to get DKIM working on the secondary install of Postfix (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179175/102085)

Putting

```
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891, inet:127.0.0.1:8893
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

On the `/etc/postfix-secondary/main.cf` doesn't work.

I believe I have everything else set up correctly.

`/etc/opendkim/KeyTable` -

```
default._domainkey.domain1.com domain1.com:default:/etc/opendkim/keys/domain1.com/default
default._domainkey.domain2.com domain2.com:default:/etc/opendkim/keys/domain2.com/default
```

`/etc/opendkim/SigningTable` -

```
domain1.com default._domainkey.domain1.com
domain2.com default._domainkey.domain2.com
```

`/etc/opendkim/Hosts` -

```
127.0.0.1
mail.domain1.com
domain1.com
host1.domain1.com
domain2.com
mail.domain2.com
host1.domain2.com
```

`/etc/opendkim.conf` -

```
AutoRestart             Yes
AutoRestartRate         10/1h
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
KeyTable                refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
LogWhy                  Yes
Mode                    sv
PidFile                 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256
SigningTable            refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
Socket                  inet:8891@localhost
Syslog                  Yes
SyslogSuccess           Yes
TemporaryDirectory      /var/tmp
UMask                   022
UserID                  opendkim:opendkim
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by adding another port

`/etc/opendkim.conf` -

```
Socket                  inet:9000@localhost
```

`/etc/postfix-secondary/main.cf` -

```
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:9000, inet:127.0.0.1:8893
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```